# Infuse flavor into dry-mushroom broth

Tags: flavor, stock

Specifically porcini powder, may occasionally add other dried mushrooms.

Epicurious simmers dry porcini uncovered one hour; NYT just 30min.
Both include veg which I won't.
This broth should be as concentrated in flavor as practical for use as seasoning not soup.

I use it in mushroom paté.
Can't add porcini powder as is to paté due to grit.
(Beware of ingredient prices too good to be true).

1.How long to simmer
2.Does adding salt or oil help to
draw out the flavor
3. Any other tips

Answer (score 2):

Porcini is a fairly strong flavor.  I can't imagine much of a difference in simmering 3o minutes or an hour.  I would start with whole, good quality (there is some variation) dehydrated porcini.  Soak or simmer.  Then, I would squeeze out the rehydrated porcini.  Strain the soaking water through a coffee filter to remove grit.  Put porcini and filtered soaking water into a high speed blender.  Blend.  Then strain and add to your pate.  Just know that porcini will be the dominant flavor of the end product, but maybe that is what you are going for.

Comment: Powder. Am starting with powder not porcini pieces.

Comment: @PatSommer...got it, I just think you will get a better result with the non-powdered version.  With powdered, you probably don't even need 30 minutes of soaking.

Comment: If you could provide any references then that would be the definitive answer. From my experience, much flavor with overnight soak after reaching boil but just my perception. The overnight is to allow grit to settle but also lose much body of broth

Comment: @PatSommer I don't have a reference. I am just speaking from experience...but why not try it yourself?  Dried porcini are easy to come by, and it is easy to grind the dried into a powder.  It would be fairly straight-forward to compare ground vs. sliced and short vs. long soak.  See which you prefer.  All versions will likely flavor your pate.

Comment: Not my question at all ground vrs soaked. Just how to get most out of my 1kg of powder. I will taste today if longer soaking makes perceivable difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to making it in a pressure cooker. That way, you definitely get much more taste out of it than by simply simmering.

You cannot add anything to "help draw out the flavor", but of course you can add ingredients which contribute their own flavor, such as salt, marmite, etc. It is better to add these after the broth has been made. I wouldn't add oil to the broth; add it to the final dish instead, at the appropriate time.

Comment: Will have to do a side by side with dry mushroom: finally got thru cheap powder. According to Cooks Illustrated:   "both the color and the flavor of the stocks noticeably different. Pressure-broth was darker, more complex, meaty flavor, while the  Dutch oven had a cleaner, purer chicken taste. What gives? Turns out high temp in pr cooker does more than just speed up the cooking time.  promotes extraction of flavor from skin and bones with breakdown of proteins into peptides, producing rich meatiness. the broth cooked in a Dutch oven tasted more like chicken but was less meaty-tasting overall."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dashi infusing method with konbu (dried kelp), unheated or heated, and check the taste each step:

1. Try a 5:1 ratio by weight porcini powder to konbu to start, in 20 parts cold water. The mushroom powder may have lost some flavour due to age with a higher surface area, so experiment with a higher ratio of mushroom powder.
2. Steep the powder and konbu, preferably overnight and in the fridge. The long cold steeping will extract the flavour without extracting alginates in the konbu that would affect texture. Do a taste test here.
3. If desired, bring the mix to a very low simmer and turn off the burner for heated extraction. Allow the mix to cool and settle before decanting.

Konbu with its glutamic acid has a synergistic effect on taste with the guanylates from mushrooms. Other foods you can consider mixing can be found on [umamiinfo](https://www.umamiinfo.com/richfood/).

Adapted from a shiitake mushroom dashi recipe from [toiro kitchen](https://toirokitchen.com/blogs/recipes/kombu-and-shiitake-mushroom-dashi).

Comment: This is an interesting idea!

Comment: Glutamic acid helps; get mine from Po Lo Ku Mushroom Seasoning Powder. Glad I finally finished that kg of powder!